# Jira - JQL - Field Text Lenght

Tags: jql

To be honest - the health of a backlog can be quickly determined by the length of a few text field lengths:

**Where project = fooBar AND Status != Done or Status != To Do AND**

1. Description < 50 characters OR
2. Acceptance Criteria < 50 characters OR
3. Definition of Done < 50 characters OR
4. Links to Design != null

If this was SQL I could do a query easily. **Does JQL have a query where I can easily do that?**

Comment: Jira doesnt support it by house. I found this Attlassian Thread which suggest to install a Plugin: https://community.atlassian.com/t5/Jira-questions/how-to-search-for-a-field-with-less-than-certain-number-of/qaq-p/1163467

Comment: Saw that - not sure regix is working as intended and doesn't take into account or's in fields needed above.

Comment: maybe u are trying to solve another problem? whats wrong with backlog? You can add it to your sprint when needed. Then I would also automatic change the status to "planed" or something else, because the sprint should be planed also.

Comment: Typically a backlog is unhealthy if it lacks Acceptance Criteria, a decent story - which falls under a Description and of course - a link to the design  / SoT / Source of Truth. Not being able to query JQL, like you could simply in SQL - makes stepping onto a new project and factually doing a query with ridiculously simple string lengths to determine the backlog health a huge pita - JQL has a long way to go. Period.